# How to wait till a stop signal in Windows?

Tags: process, windows-services, createprocess, srvany

`srvany-next` is my open source command-line utility that allows to start another command-line utility as a Windows service:

```bash
srvany-next.exe "c:\bin\utility.exe" -arguments
```

The above is the command that starts `utility.exe` as a Windows service.

This is code from my open source utility [srvany-next](https://github.com/vporton/srvany-next), old version:

```c
    if (CreateProcess(global_argv[1], applicationParameters, NULL, NULL, FALSE, dwFlags, applicationEnvironment, applicationDirectory, &startupInfo, &g_Process))
    {
        ServiceSetState(SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP, SERVICE_RUNNING, 0);
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if (hThread == NULL)
        {
            ServiceSetState(0, SERVICE_STOPPED, GetLastError());
            return;
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE); //Wait here for a stop signal.
    }
    CloseHandle(g_ServiceStopEvent);
    ServiceSetState(0, SERVICE_STOPPED, 0);
```

and new version:

```c
    if (CreateProcess(global_argv[1], applicationParameters, NULL, NULL, FALSE, dwFlags, applicationEnvironment, applicationDirectory, &startupInfo, &g_Process))
    {
        ServiceSetState(SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP, SERVICE_RUNNING, 0);
        Sleep(INFINITE);
    }
    CloseHandle(g_ServiceStopEvent);
    ServiceSetState(0, SERVICE_STOPPED, 0);
```

Previously, it worked. But after changing the software that is launched by `CreateProcess`, `WaitForSingleObject` started to exit immediately (why?). I commented it out and replaces by `Sleep`. Now, when I start the service using Windows Services app, it appears to start; but I don't see log of my app (that is to be started by `CreateProcess`) and can't connect to it by HTTP; also GNU utility `ps` does not show it running. So, it appears that the app started by `CreateProcess` does not really start.

When I start it (without `srvany-next`, that is not as a service) from command line under admin account, it works.

Is using `Sleep` here correct? Don't we need to process process starting events? (if in Windows there are process starting events) I suspect that `Sleep` blocks processing of events and therefore `CreateProcess` is not fully executed. Or why else may it not work?

You have [the full source](https://github.com/vporton/srvany-next) and a welcome to contribute, as it is a useful Windows software.

Comment: There are lots of questions here. You should check WaitForSingleObject result value, it may return an error. Sleep is rarely a good idea since it depends on the timings, the machine and everything one cannot control, and is often a bad smell. Sleep infinite is worse as it can hang a thread/process. If you really want to use Sleep you should put it in a loop with small sleep values (until the total is more than something big like minutes). Also you shouldn't set SERVICE_STOPPED if your process has successfully started